# How to Save Configuation in app.config in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

Can someone give me an example of how to save a key/value in app.config using `C#` and WinForms?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In *ASP.NET*:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
app.Settings.Add("x", "this is X");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

In *WinForms*:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
app.Settings.Add("x", "this is X");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: when i open app.config it not write "x" and "this is x"

Comment: @monkey_boys: When running e.g. a win forms application from VS, the relevant .config file to look for is: <My application>.vshost.exe.config, so if you were looking in <My application>.exe.config then you don't see any change.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani no, it adds a new comma-separated value.

Answer (score 3):

I know you specifically asked for WinForms solution, but this might help some others.  For a .NET 4.0 console application, none of these worked for me. So I used the following and it worked:

```
private static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.
        OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configuration.Save();

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be :
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810043157/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx)

Comment: why i cant see ConfigurationManager class

Comment: add : 
using System.Configuration;

in the using section